# jQuery UI Sortable with minimize and maximize

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery UI Sortable for my current project and I just found from jQuery site and I want to **Feeds** maximize and other are minimize.

My jsFiddle : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7DM3Q/)

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks.

My Code:

```
$(function() {
    $(".column").sortable({
        connectWith: ".column"
    });
    $(".portlet").addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all").find(".portlet-header").addClass("ui-widget-header ui-corner-all").prepend("<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick'></span>").end().find(".portlet-content");
    $(".portlet-header .ui-icon").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("ui-icon-minusthick").toggleClass("ui-icon-plusthick");
        $(this).parents(".portlet:first").find(".portlet-content").toggle();
    });
    $(".column").disableSelection();
});
```

Comment: Do you want all boxes apart from Feeds closed/minimized when you first load the page?

Comment: ya i want feed open by default and other are closed/minimized

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give an ID to feed div and add this 3 lines, DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/7DM3Q/2/

```
// to open only feed
$('.portlet-content').css({'display':'none'});
$('#feed .portlet-content').css({'display':'block'});
// to change plus icon of feed
$("#feed .portlet-header span").removeClass("ui-icon-minusthick").addClass("ui-icon-plusthick");
```

## JQUERY

```
$(function () {
    $('.portlet-content').css({'display':'none'});
    $('#feed .portlet-content').css({'display':'block'});
    
    $(".column").sortable({
        connectWith: ".column"
    });
    $(".portlet").addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all")
        .find(".portlet-header")
        .addClass("ui-widget-header ui-corner-all")
        .prepend("<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick'></span>")
        .end()
        .find(".portlet-content");
    
    $("#feed .portlet-header span").removeClass("ui-icon-minusthick").addClass("ui-icon-plusthick");
    
    $(".portlet-header .ui-icon").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("ui-icon-minusthick").toggleClass("ui-icon-plusthick");
        $(this).parents(".portlet:first").find(".portlet-content").toggle();
    });
    $(".column").disableSelection();
});
```

Comment: check my update answer again, you still need 1 more script to change plus icon of #feed.